# Trouble using two models in one view for backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having trouble in attempting to use two models with the same view in backbone.js. Somehow the view is being rendered before the triggers are getting triggered to begin the render function.

Here are the models:

```
APP.Models.FamilyPreferences = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function( attributes, options ) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'success_handler', 'populate');
        this.url = options.url;
    },
    populate: function(){
        this.fetch({success: this.success_handler});
    },
    success_handler: function(){
        this.trigger("change");
    }
});
APP.Models.Preferences = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function( attributes, options ) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'success_handler', 'error_handler', 'populate');
        this.url = options.url;
    },
    populate: function(){
        this.fetch({success: this.success_handler, error:this.error_handler}); 
    },
    success_handler: function(){
        this.exists = true;
        this.trigger("change");
    },
    error_handler: function(){
        this.exists = false;
        this.trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Here is the relevant code from the view:

```
APP.Views.PreferencesFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
templates: [{name:"preferences_template", file_path:"preferences_form.html"}],

initialize: function(options){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderPrereq');
    var family_url = "services/family/" + options.family_id;
    var preferences_url = "services/preferences/familyID/" + options.family_id;
    var ctx = this;
    this.alreadyRendered = false;
    this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded = [];

    this.models = {};

    this.models.family = new APP.Models.FamilyPreferences({}, {url: family_url});
    this.models.family.on('change', function(){ctx.renderPrereq("family");});
    this.models.family.populate();

    this.models.preferences = new APP.Models.Preferences({}, {url:preferences_url});
    this.models.preferences.on('change', function() {ctx.renderPrereq("preferences");});
    this.models.preferences.populate();
},

renderPrereq: function(newmodel){
    var inside = ($.inArray(newmodel, this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded)>-1) ? true : false;
    if (!(inside)){this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded.push(newmodel);}

    var total = Object.keys(this.models).length;
    if(this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded.length == total && !this.alreadyRendered){
        this.alreadyRendered = true;
        this.render();
    }
},
render: function(){

    var family_data = {
        id: this.models.family.attributes.id,
        familyGroup: this.models.family.attributes.groupNum,
        familyId: this.models.family.attributes.familyId,
        probandDob: this.models.family.attributes.childDob,
    }

    var preferences_data = {
        mother: this.models.preferences.attributes[0],
        father: this.models.preferences.attributes[1],
        exists: this.models.preferences.exists
    }

    this.$el.html(this.compiledTemplates.preferences_template(family_data));
    //bunch of javascript making the page work
}
});
```

The template are getting loaded through another js function elsewhere that to the best of my knowledge is working correctly. Somehow the render function is getting called before the success handlers. I can't figure out how. The only side effect it has is that the Preferences model doesn't get the exists property and is hence undefined which cause all sorts of problems. Also, options.family_id is set correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: It also seems to be going to renderPrereq up to six times which I also can't figure out.

**JSON - Family model**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "familyId": "family01",
    "collectionDate": "2013-01-01",
    "childDob": "2001-05-‌​06",
    "groupNum": "Two",
    "probands": [],
    "mother": null,
    "father": null,
    "siblings": []
}
```

**JSON - First part of Preferences Model**

```
[{
    "main": "illness-only",
    "obesity": "No",
    "bloodPressure": "No",
    "diabetes": "No",
    "hea‌​rt": "No",
    "alzheimers": "No",
    "parkinsons": "No",
    "mentalHealth": "No",
    "breastOvarianCa‌​ncer": "No",
    "prostateTesticularCancer": "No",
    "otherCancer": "No",
    "childSickleCell": "‌​No",
    "childCysticFibrosis": "No",
    "childMuscularDystrophy": "No",
    "childAutism": "No"
}, 
{
    "main":"more-questions",
    "obesity":"No",
    "bloodPressure":"Yes",
    "diabetes":"No",
    "heart":"Unsure",
    "alzheimers":"No",
    "parkinsons":"Yes",
    "mentalHealth":"No",
    "breastOvarianCancer":"No",
    "prostateTesticularCancer":"No",
    "otherCancer":"No",
    "childSickleCell":"No",
    "childCysticFibrosis":"No",
    "childMuscularDystrophy":"No",
    "childAutism":"No"}]
```

**Headers**

```
Accept: application / json, text / javascript, /; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch 
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8  
Cache-Control:no-cache Connection:keep-alive     
Cookie:csrftoken=bDIpdvAPBdWF6dZe9BkpsFSF4wiGl2qX 
Host:localhost:8080 Pragma:no-cache  Referer:localhost:8080/CSER / index.html 
User - Agent: Mozilla / 5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit /
537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 27.0.1453.110 Safari / 537.36 X - Requested - With: XMLHttpRequest
```

**Try this code ..**

```
APP.Models.FamilyPreferences = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (attributes, options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'success_handler', 'populate');
        this.url = options.url;
    },
    populate: function () {
        this.fetch();
    },
    // This is not required
    // It will automatically render it as we are listening to the sync event
    success_handler: function () {
        // Not required 
        // sync event will take care of it
    }
});
APP.Models.Preferences = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (attributes, options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'success_handler', 'error_handler', 'populate');
        this.url = options.url;
    },
    populate: function () {
        this.fetch({
            success: this.success_handler,
            error: this.error_handler
        });
    },
    success_handler: function () {
        this.exists = true;
        // Not required 
        // sync event will take care of it
    },
    error_handler: function () {
       // Do something else
    }
});

APP.Views.PreferencesFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    templates: [{
        name: "preferences_template",
        file_path: "preferences_form.html"
    }],

    initialize: function (options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderPrereq');
        var family_url = "services/family/" + options.family_id;
        var preferences_url = "services/preferences/familyID/" + options.family_id;
        var ctx = this;
        this.alreadyRendered = false;
        this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded = [];

        this.models = {};
        // Family Model
        this.models.family = new APP.Models.FamilyPreferences({}, {
            url: family_url
        });

        this.listenTo( this.models.family, 'change', function () {
            ctx.renderPrereq("family");
        });
        // This will take care of rendering it on Sync with server
        // No need to triggereing the event explicitly..
        this.listenTo( this.models.family, 'sync', function () {
            ctx.renderPrereq("family");
        });        

        this.models.family.populate();

        // Family Preference Model
        this.models.preferences = new APP.Models.Preferences({}, {
            url: preferences_url
        });

        this.listenTo( this.models.preferences, 'change', function () {
            ctx.renderPrereq("family");
        });
        // This will take care of rendering it on Sync with server
        // No need to triggereing the event explicitly..
        this.listenTo( this.models.preferences, 'sync', function () {
            ctx.renderPrereq("preferences");
        });  
        this.models.preferences.populate();
    },

    renderPrereq: function (newmodel) {
        var inside = ($.inArray(newmodel, this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded) > -1) ? true : false;
        if (!(inside)) {
            this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded.push(newmodel);
        }

        var total = Object.keys(this.models).length;
        if (this.modelsCurrentlyLoaded.length == total && !this.alreadyRendered) {
            this.alreadyRendered = true;
            this.render();
        }
    },
    render: function () {

        var family_data = this.models.family.toJSON());

        var preferences_data = {
            mother: this.models.preferences.attributes[0],
            father: this.models.preferences.attributes[1],
            exists: this.models.preferences.get('exists') ? this.models.preferences.get('exists') : false
        }

        this.$el.html(this.compiledTemplates.preferences_template(family_data);
        //bunch of javascript making the page work
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the way it is constructed... I don't think the `render` is called before `success_handler` .

If you look at the `renderPrereq` method , 2 models on change will call this method on success.

But the `fetch` methods are async. So you never know which handler will be called first.

And when the `change` on the model is triggered. This calls the `render` method which is inside the `renderPrereq` method.

Comment: If I debug it, It goes to the render function (renderPrereq for that matter) before the success handler. Sometimes (rarely) it works.

It shouldn't matter which model gets called first, since it can't go into the if statement in the renderPrereq without having both models pass. Unless I'm drastically misunderstanding something.

Comment: Can you create a working example ? Also can you paste the url request that is being sent ... ?

Comment: This is my first attempt at a working example. I'm not going off anything else. I can make working examples for one model. 

I'm not sure exactly what you mean as far as the url request. I am getting back all of the information correctly except for the exist field which is undefined and not a boolean value as it should be.

Comment: I meant , the model data is populated when a fetch request is sent to the server. And I cannot replicate that right.. I wanted to see how the request and response for each model is when the url is hit

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just not sure what you want me to send you. I'd like to know. The response is a json full of a bunch of data from a jax-rs rest java program accessing a mysql db. The json is correct when I manually force it to work.

Comment: If you have the developer tools open and run the code.. You can see the request in the Network tab.. In there there are 2 more tabs called Headers and Response.. I wanted to see that particular context and also the json..

Comment: I can only find a response tab but the request seems to be a GET; 200 OK status; application/json for type. That is for both. the JSON response is {"id":1,"familyId":"family01","collectionDate":"2013-01-01","childDob":"2001-05-06","groupNum":"Two","probands":[],"mother":null,"father":null,"siblings":[]} for family and...

Comment: the other one is too long for the comments... but the first half is [{"main":"illness-only","obesity":"No","bloodPressure":"No","diabetes":"No","heart":"No","alzheimers":"No","parkinsons":"No","mentalHealth":"No","breastOvarianCancer":"No","prostateTesticularCancer":"No","otherCancer":"No","childSickleCell":"No","childCysticFibrosis":"No","childMuscularDystrophy":"No","childAutism":"No"} and then another almost identical.

Comment: from preferences Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:csrftoken=bDIpdvAPBdWF6dZe9BkpsFSF4wiGl2qX
Host:localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/CSER/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: close... I was expecting even the `Request url ` and `Request Method`

Comment: /CSER/services/family and /CSER/services/preference they are both GETS

Comment: I observed one thing .. Why are you not using justthis.models.family.toJSON() instead of constructing the `JSON` object specifically

Comment: Also whenever possible use `model.get(attributeName)` instead of directly accessing the `attributes` object.

Comment: Then replace the exists with this line.. This will pass in false if the attribute is not available.. `exists: this.models.preferences.get('exists') ? this.models.preferences.get('exists') : false`

Comment: And the `exists` attribute is not being set on the model as it is being overwritten after the model is repopulated from the server.. I think you need to pass in extra option like `{merge: true}` for the fetch so that it does not overwrite the exists attr

Comment: Now lastly.. Try listening to `sync` event instead of `change` .. I feel the change event is being triggered for change for each single attribute value... And you need not explicity trigger the event in the first place.. The `sync` event will take care of that

Comment: @TheComposer.. Check edited code.. I have made some changes to the code on what I think !!

Comment: I figure out my issue. The problem was that I didn't know change got fired by default. I didn't realize I was refiring the same event manually. The key being refiring. Your changes would have fixed that too.

Comment: Cheers... Just avoid triggering the events unless and absolutely necessary .. :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I'll use some of your suggestions in the future.